# How to revert halfway installed magento2 code dump?

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.0, installation, local.xml

My secnario is like this. When we use magento 1.x versions , assume while installing we got an error. So what we simply do is delete app/etc/local.xml and empty the var/session and var/cache directories. And once the database is dropped and re-created we can run the installation again.

Is there a similar way for magento2 ?  (Rather than extracting always from the original?)

Answer (score 2):

> So what we simply do is delete app/etc/local.xml and empty the var/session and var/cache directories

The equivalent of this in Magento 2 would be:

- delete `app/etc/env.php`
- empty the `var` folders

On the other hand I suggest you should use the Magento 2 CLI and try something like this:

```
php bin/magento setup:uninstall
php bin/magento setup:install
```

Comment: Wow. Impressive! Will give it a try.